# What is the meaning of «Chien(ne) de garde»?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> «Chien(ne) de garde»

I have seen this expression in a lot of political contexts. For example:

> «Les médias, chiens de garde de l'ordre établi ?».

Ideally, I would like the answer to come in the form of an English idiom, not a literal translation. Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44565/discussion-on-question-by-erwann-what-is-the-meaning-of-chienne-de-garde).

Comment: Considering the answers, one would only need to replace the second sentence with something like "I would like to know the meaning of this idiom in such contexts" and I would gladly cast a reopen vote on that. Thanks.

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ So would I. OP  was asked to do modify his question, he didn't.  A case study on how  bad questions can nevertheless generate good answers.

Answer (score 5):

“*Chien de garde*” (“*chiens de garde*” is the plural, ”*chienne de garde*” the feminine form) means guard dog or watchdog. A *chien de garde* may not only bark if there are intruders, but also attack intruders.

In French idioms, dogs usually have a negative connotation, but not systematically so. Dogs can be dirty, aggressive and stupid but can also be loyal.

To say that someone is the *chien de garde* of someone else means that they defend that person against attacks. It implies that the *chien* is under control of the person being defended and that they defend them whether they are right or wrong — a dog defends its master.

There is a history in France of calling journalists “*chiens de garde*” of the establishment (which is what “*l'ordre établi*” means), of the political and economic leaders. I think this use of the term originates with a [1997 essay “*Les Nouveaux Chiens de garde*”](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Nouveaux_Chiens_de_garde) by [French journalist Serge Halimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Halimi). The expression in turn echoed [a 1932 essay by Paul Nizan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Chiens_de_garde), where the *chiens de garde* of capitalism were some philosophers of the time, accused of not caring about the common people and thus supporting the rich in class warfare. Halimi's essay was [made into a film of the same name](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Nouveaux_Chiens_de_garde_(film)), the expression only took off after that.

In English, this expression has often been translated as “guard dogs” (as in “[new guard dogs of capitalism](https://www.google.com/#q=%22guard+dogs+of+capitalism%22)”). “*Chiens de garde*” a bit different from “[running dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_dog)” (a literal translation of a Chinese pejorative expression) because *running dog* only conveys the blind obedience aspect, whereas a *chien de garde* is active in defense of its master.

Note that calling someone “*chien de garde*”  without specifying that they are guarding a particular person or group of persons could have a very different, positive connotation, comparable to the English “watchdog” — a dog who detects unwelcome events.

Comment: Note that both [Nizan's essay](http://bit.ly/2bykuM8) and [S. Halimi's](http://bit.ly/2bGEgqo) were translated into Englih with the term "watchdogs" (and not guard dogs).

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence "les médias, chiens de garde de l'ordre établi ?", the best translation for *chiens de garde* is "watchdog" which is defined by the Cambridge dictionary as

> a person or organization responsible for making certain that companies obey particular standards and do not act illegally

You also suggested "chienne de garde". It is interesting because it should only be used as an equivalent for *female guard dog* since its other translation would be *watchbitch*, which is of course offensive. However, a French feminist movement has named itself [les Chiennes de garde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Chiennes_de_garde). They are watchdogs primarily against sexist insults in the media.

Comment: You reply includes a tangentially interesting point about the feminist movement named «Chiennes de garde», but, for the rest, it disregards points have already been raised, explicitly or implicitly. If I follow your line of thought, and apply to the example I gave in my question, the media are "responsible for making certain people think the way establishment wants them to". They are supposed to be the watchdog of neutrality.

Comment: The true meaning of the example title depends on the article. I reckon it is a sarcastic title and a criticism against media which may be not neutral enough.

Comment: Bottom line: "are the media the watchdog of the establishment?" is awkward, as "watchdog" connotes virtue.

Comment: That is where the irony is. Consider this rephrasing: media proudly call themselves watchdog but they actually do not fight establishment, they promote it. It is roughly the same, without the irony the French like so much.

Comment: I'm glad with are on the same page about the meaning of watchdog.

Comment: All things considered, I think «Chien de garde» translates to «lackey», in this context: «have the media become the lackey of the establishment?».

Comment: I find your answer misleading. The definition you quote does not correspond to the meaning of “chiens de garde” in this context. In this context, the journalists are defending the establishment against what people who use the expression “chiens de garde” consider to be valid accusations of not obeying ethical standards.

Comment: “Chiennes de garde” does not have a more negative connotation than “chiens de garde”. “Chienne” in French is not at all like “bitch” in English, it is not dominated by an insulting meaning. A *chienne* in most contexts is just the female form of *dog* (there are contexts where it is an insult directed to a woman, but they're rare, not systematic like “bitch”).